# How to wrap column data in birt report

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, report, birt

Text wrap in Table cell - so value came in next row and not cut half way.
use this code in expression to achieve result.

```js
 if (dataSetRow["cell_name"]== null) { '' }
   else {
     function wrap(longStr,width)
      { 
       length = longStr.length;
      if(length <= width) 
          return longStr;
      return (longStr.substring(0, width) + "\n" + wrap(longStr.substring(width, length), width)); }         
 
 
     wrap( dataSetRow["cell_name"], 5 );
 
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks totally fine. Just put it into your dynamic Text field.

[image: JavaScript defined dynamic text]

Answer (score 0):

Above are correct, after add the code need to whitespace change to auto.[image]